# How to extract the 95% CI for boxcox in R

Tags: r

```
boxcox(Volume ~ log(Height) + log(Girth), data = trees,
   lambda = seq(-0.25, 0.25, length = 10))
```

My question is that without plotting the result, how to extract the 95% confidence interval (CI) of lambda?
I want to examine if 1 is within the CI. If so, I won't transform the data, otherwise, I'll transform with the data with lambda with highest likelihood.

The above code is just an example of boxcox in R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it.

```
bc = boxcox(Volume ~ log(Height) + log(Girth), data = trees,lambda = seq(-0.25, 0.25, length = 10))

bc$x[bc$y > max(bc$y) - 1/2 * qchisq(.95,1)]
```

would work.

Reference: Linear Models With R by Julian Faraway Section 8.1.